# SQL to GROUP BY calculated date

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, ms-access, group-by

I need some assistance in grouping data by date via SQL but seem to be running into errors.

Here's my current SQL statement used as a variable passed into Excel VBA macro.

```
SQLtext = "SELECT [Offered], [MidnightStartDate], tblConfig_Queue.[Name], tblConfig_Queue.[Reporting]" & _
"FROM tblData_QueuePerformanceByPeriod INNER JOIN tblConfig_Queue on tblConfig_Queue.Pkey = tblData_QueuePerformanceByPeriod.FKQueue " & _
"Where [Offered]>0 AND[MidnightStartDate]>" & MakeUSSQLDate(Sheet13.Range("A1").Value) & " AND [MidnightStartDate]<" & MakeUSSQLDate(Sheet13.Range("A2").Value + 1) & _
""
```

The field MidnightStartDate is a date & time field in a US format. The MakeUSSQLDate procedure converts this into a UK format. I then want to remove any time values from the field, and have date only, and group by this field to give me a total of [Offered] for each of the [Name] and [Reporting] values for each date. I have used the convert function to strip out the times, and this currently works as below.

```
SQLtext = "SELECT [Offered], convert(varchar, [MidnightStartDate], 103) AS [Date2], tblConfig_Queue.[Name], tblConfig_Queue.[Reporting]" & _
"FROM tblData_QueuePerformanceByPeriod INNER JOIN tblConfig_Queue on tblConfig_Queue.Pkey = tblData_QueuePerformanceByPeriod.FKQueue " & _
"Where [Offered]>0 AND[MidnightStartDate]>" & MakeUSSQLDate(Sheet13.Range("A1").Value) & " AND [MidnightStartDate]<" & MakeUSSQLDate(Sheet13.Range("A2").Value + 1) & _
""
```

However I can't seem to get the thing to group by the date. I have added `GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar, [MidnightStartDate], 103) ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar, [MidnightStartDate], 103)` to the end of the SQL statement in an attempt to solve this but only get error messages back.

Comment: Could you post the errors?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I get the following error:
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Column 'tblData_QueuePerformanceByPeriod.Offered' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I have now included tblConfig_Queue.[Name], tblConfig_Queue.[Reporting] in my GROUP BY, but the total of [Offered] doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Thanks everyone - it's all working now .The total seems to be correct when i change SELECT [Offered] to SELECT SUM([Offered]). I also removed [Offered] from the GROUP BY statement as it was causing errors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm waiting for your error but...

If you use GROUP BY as follow:

```
convert(varchar, [MidnightStartDate], 103)
```

and you have in the SELECT fields these fields:

```
[Offered], convert(varchar, [MidnightStartDate], 103),
tblConfig_Queue.[Name], tblConfig_Queue.[Reporting]
```

It's logic the error, because you must add all fields in your group by clause.

When you use a GROUP BY in the SELECTE field list you can have only:

- Constants
- Grouped fields
- Aggregate functions

So you must extend your GROUP BY clause like the following:

```
GROUP BY [Offered], convert(varchar, [MidnightStartDate], 103) AS [Date2],
tblConfig_Queue.[Name], tblConfig_Queue.[Reporting]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your error is to do with not including your other fields or wrapping them in an aggregate function try:

```
SQLtext = "SELECT [Offered], convert(varchar, [MidnightStartDate], 103) AS [Date2], tblConfig_Queue.[Name], tblConfig_Queue.[Reporting]" & _
"FROM tblData_QueuePerformanceByPeriod INNER JOIN tblConfig_Queue ON tblConfig_Queue.Pkey = tblData_QueuePerformanceByPeriod.FKQueue " & _
"WHERE [Offered]>0 AND [MidnightStartDate]>" & MakeUSSQLDate(Sheet13.Range("A1").Value) & " AND [MidnightStartDate]<" & MakeUSSQLDate(Sheet13.Range("A2").Value + 1) & _
"GROUP BY convert(varchar, [MidnightStartDate], 103), [Offered], tblConfig_Queue.[Name], tblConfig_Queue.[Reporting]" & _
"ORDER BY convert(varchar, [MidnightStartDate], 103)" & _
""
```

Cleaning up with `BETWEEN`

```
SQLtext = "SELECT [Offered], convert(varchar, [MidnightStartDate], 103) AS [Date2], tblConfig_Queue.[Name], tblConfig_Queue.[Reporting]" & _
"FROM tblData_QueuePerformanceByPeriod INNER JOIN tblConfig_Queue ON tblConfig_Queue.Pkey = tblData_QueuePerformanceByPeriod.FKQueue " & _
"WHERE [Offered]>0 AND [MidnightStartDate] BETWEEN" & MakeUSSQLDate(Sheet13.Range("A1").Value) & " AND " & MakeUSSQLDate(Sheet13.Range("A2").Value + 1) & _
"GROUP BY convert(varchar, [MidnightStartDate], 103), [Offered], tblConfig_Queue.[Name], tblConfig_Queue.[Reporting]" & _
"ORDER BY convert(varchar, [MidnightStartDate], 103)" & _
""
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help - my final working code

```
SQLtext = "SELECT SUM([Offered]), CAST([MidnightStartDate] AS INT), tblConfig_Queue.[Name], tblConfig_Queue.[Reporting]" & _
"FROM tblData_QueuePerformanceByPeriod INNER JOIN tblConfig_Queue on tblConfig_Queue.Pkey = tblData_QueuePerformanceByPeriod.FKQueue " & _
"Where [Offered]>0 AND[MidnightStartDate]>" & MakeUSSQLDate(Sheet13.Range("A1").Value) & " AND [MidnightStartDate]<" & MakeUSSQLDate(Sheet13.Range("A2").Value + 1) & _
"GROUP BY CAST([MidnightStartDate] AS INT), tblConfig_Queue.[Name], tblConfig_Queue.[Reporting]" & _
"ORDER BY CAST([MidnightStartDate] AS INT), tblConfig_Queue.[Reporting];"
```